AWS Lambda function only detects my express root path and ignores the other multiple routes
I've succesfully uploaded my image to ECR, linked it to my AWS Lambda function and configured an ANY proxy using an API Gateway. My root endpoint works fine but other routes are ignored and return the response to my root endpoint.
The cloudwatch logs don't display any error so I'm stuck and not sure how to go about this. What I'm I missing?
Here's my configuration
My lambda function
const app = require('./api');
const serverless = require('serverless-http');
module.exports.handler = serverless(app);
My API.JS file in the same path
....
app.get('/v1/test', (req, res) => {
return res.status(200).json({
message: 'Successfully tested api',
data: [],
});
});
app.get('/api/info', (req, res) => {
res.send({ application: 'my-express-app-as-lambda', version: '1' });
});
const routesIndex = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/v1', routesIndex);
app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
res.send('Welcome to the Premier League Trivia API - Enjoy the game!');
return res.status(200);
});
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
next(createError(404));
});
app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
res.status(error.status || 500).json({
error: {
message: error?.message,
details: error?.details,
},
});
});
module.exports = app;
My team.js file
const router = require('express').Router();
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
try {
return res.status(200).json({
message: 'Successfully retrieved all teams',
data: [],
});
} catch (error) {
return res.status(500).json({
message: 'An error occurred',
error,
});
}
});
module.exports = router;
